# Kalabox Drush failins. Can I run a bash shell in the created Docker container instead?

Tags: docker

The documented [kbox command](http://docs.kalabox.io/en/stable/users/cli/) `kbox drush` command fails. I've found two similar issues: [#361](https://github.com/kalabox/kalabox/issues/361) and [362](https://github.com/kalabox/kalabox/issues/362).

```
$ kbox drush cron
```

> Command core-cron needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command. The drush command 'cron' could not be executed.                      Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.

and

```
 Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.51                           
 Site URI               :  my_project_alpha.kbox            
 Database driver        :  sqlite                         
 Database name          :  sites/default/files/.ht.sqlite 
 PHP configuration      :                                 
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                          
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush           
 Drush version          :  8.0.5                          
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                           
 Drush configuration    :  /home/1000/.drush/drushrc.php  
 Drush alias files      :                                 
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html                  
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php     
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

So with a normal `docker` container, I can [run a shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/507009/57914) via

`sudo docker exec -i -t abcdef123456 /bin/bash`

**Question(s):** Can I do something similar with the container set up via Kalabox? Can I find which docker container that Kalabox has set up? Can I interact with the container via docker cli?

Comment: check out `docker ps -a`, this shoudl list all docker containers, running or otherwise on the host, and see if it helps you point out the container that you are interested in

Comment: If you do a `docker ps`, that should show all running containers. If kalabox uses your existing docker daemon, I'd expect that any containers it has started should show up there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers are based on images. So when you say a normal container, I am assuming it is probably based on one of the tutorials that use some linux based image.

Do a `docker ps -a` this would list all containers running or otherwise. 
Use the image details in there, to figure out what is your Kalabox container.

Then do a `sudo docker exec -ti <container_id> /bin/bash`. 
This should land you into the container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you RTFM the kalabox docs? Seems like this is covered
http://docs.kalabox.io/en/stable/general/engine/#engine-for-macoswin

Re: `kbox drush cron`. The most obvious thing to mention is that your DB credentials may not be set up correctly.